# Making an HTTPs request on AWS ApiGatewayV2 websocket connection to Respond, or Delete it

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

### UPDATE

This issue is partially resolved, the problem now lies in authenticating the ApiGateway request. I am unsure of how to acquire the necessary tokens to send with the request so that it is valid, because this is a [serverless-framework] service so I can't use the AWS Console to copy paste the tokens into the request's json data. Moreover, I wouldn't know what json key they'd have to be under anyways. So I guess this question has changed considerably in scope.

---

I need to respond/delete an active websocket connection established through AWS ApiGatewayV2, in a Lambda. How do I use node js to send a `POST` request that ApiGateway can understand?

I saw on [the websocket support announcement video](https://youtu.be/3SCdzzD0PdQ?t=697) that you could issue an HTTP `POST` request to respond to a websocket, and `DELETE` request to disconnect a websocket. Full table from the video transcribed here:

```
Connection URL
https://abcdef.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/env/@connections/connectionId

Operation  Action
POST       Sends a message from the Server to connected WS Client
GET        Gets the latest connection status of the connected WS Client
DELETE     Disconnect the connected client from the WS connection
```

(this is not documented anywhere else, AFAIK)

Seeing as the AWS SDK does not provide a deleteConnection method on [ApiGatewayManagementApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ApiGatewayManagementApi.html), I need to be able to issue requests directly to the ApiGateway anyways.

```
const connect = async (event, context) => {
  const connection_id = event.requestContext.connectionId;
  const host = event.requestContext.domainName;
  const path = '/' + event.requestContext.stage + '/@connections/';
  const json = JSON.stringify({data: "hello world!"});

  console.log("send to " + host + path + connection_id + ":\n" + json);

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      host: host,
      port: '443',
      path: path + connection_id,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(json)
      }
    };
    const req = https.request(
      options,
      (res) => {
        res.on('data', (data) => {
          console.error(data.toString());
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
          console.error("request finished");
          resolve();
        });
        res.on('error', (error) => {
          console.error(error, error.stack);
          reject();
        });
      }
    );
    req.write(json);
    req.end();
  });
  return success;
};
```

When I use `wscat` to test it out, this code results in the `console.log` showing up in CloudWatch:

```
send to ********.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/@connections/*************:
{
    "data": "hello world!"
}

...

{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}

...

request finished
```

And `wscat` says:

```
connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
>
```

But does not print `hello world!` or similar.

### Edit

I was missing

```
res.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(data.toString());
});
```

in the response handler, which was breaking things. This still doesnt work, though.

Comment: what does your `serverless.yml` look like? Do you mind adding it to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely missing two things here.

1. You need to make an IAM signed request to the API Gateway per the documentation located here: [Use @connections Commands in Your Backend Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html)
2. You'll need to give this lambda permission to invoke the API Gateway per the documentation here: [Use IAM Authorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-control-access-iam.html)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've seen this doc page, but it leaves out the most crucial part to a comment: `// Do a SigV4 and then make the call`. Maybe I'm missing some obvious way to do it? About the lambda permissions, I *think* I've got that set up correctly, since I use serverless-framework to do it. (I think its automatic?)

Comment: You can use an NPM package like [aws4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) to generate the sig4 requests.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly what I needed!